# Data truncation error when adding date(using JCalendar) in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am inserting data into a form to MySQL database but when I am setting a date in the date field(using JCalendar/JDateChooser) in the form, I am getting a Data Truncation error like *Got an exception!
Data truncation: Incorrect date value: 'Mar 10, 2016' for column 'arrival_date' at row 1* as the date I entered was that of Mar 10, 2016.

Here is my code:

```
             Connection conn = null;

            // the mysql insert statement
         String insertTable = "INSERT INTO booking" + 
         "(fname,lname,contact,email,address, num_persons, arrival_date,departure_date,arrival_time,room_type,view_type,roomno,room_facility )VALUES" 
         + "(? , ? , ? , ?,? , ? , ? , ?,? , ? , ? , ?,?)";

            try {

                // create a mysql database connection
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
                String connectionUser = "root";
                String connectionPassword = "admin";
                conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser,connectionPassword);

                // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
                PreparedStatement preparedStmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(insertTable);

                preparedStmt.setString(1,fnameField.getText() );
                preparedStmt.setString(2,(lnameField.getText()));
                preparedStmt.setString(3,(contactField.getText()));
                preparedStmt.setString(4,(emailField.getText()));
                preparedStmt.setString(5,(txtadd.getText()));
                preparedStmt.setString(6,(spinner.getValue().toString()));
                preparedStmt.setString(7,((JTextField)dateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
                preparedStmt.setString(8,((JTextField)dateChooser2.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
                preparedStmt.setString(9,(timeSpinner.getValue().toString()));
                preparedStmt.setString(10,rtype);
                preparedStmt.setString(11,vtype);
                preparedStmt.setString(12,(txtroomnum.getText()));
                preparedStmt.setString(13,room_facility);

             // execute the preparedstatement
                preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
                conn.close();
```

And here is my table for the database:

```
 create table booking(
booking_id int unsigned auto_increment not null,
fname varchar(50) not null,
lname varchar(50) not null,
contact int,
email varchar(75),
address varchar(200),
num_persons int,
arrival_date date,
departure_date date,
arrival_time time,
room_type tinyint(1) not null,//for radiobuttons
view_type tinyint(1) not null,//for radiobuttons
roomno int,
room_facility tinyint(1) not null,//for multiple selection of checkboxes(not sure if the data type is correct here)
primary key(booking_id)
);
```

Here is my form to show the fields and the format in which the date appears :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't do `preparedStmt.setString(7,((JTextField)dateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());`.

Seriously, if you're going to store date/time data in a database, start by using the appropriate data type for the column.

Start by getting the `Date` value from the editor...

```
java.util.Date utilDate = dateChooser1.getDate();
```

Then wrap it in a `java.sql.Date`

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Then use `PreparedStatement#setDate` to bind the value to the query...

```
preparedStmt.setDate(7, sqlDate);
```

Then let the JDBC driver figure it out.

There are any number of good reasons for doing this, apart from storing data in the most appropriate format, you can know query the database using it's own date/time functionality and you no longer care about the format the database "might" use to store the data

Comment: Shouldn't it be `utilDate.getTime()`?

Comment: I just changed `date.getTime` to `utilDate.getTime` and I got this message: *Got an exception!
Data truncation: Incorrect time value: 'Sat Mar 05 03:34:16 GST 2016' for column 'arrival_time' at row 1*

Comment: The incorrect time value was the current date and time actually( that is of today and now)

Comment: @Diksha What is the column type in the database? You might need to use `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of `java.sql.Date` and then use `PreparedStatement#setTimestamp` - alternativly, you might be able to use `java.sql.Time` depending on if you're trying to capture just the date or time values

Comment: `date`  I have added my database table in the body of my ques

Comment: Also make sure you change both columns `7` and `8` to use the same method (and `java.sql.Date` is the correct class for the `DATE` type)

Comment: Yup, I did so : ` java.util.Date utilDate1 = dateChooser1.getDate();`
              `java.sql.Date sqlDate1 = new java.sql.Date(utilDate1.getTime()); `

Comment: ` preparedStmt.setDate(8, sqlDate1);`

Comment: Then your next problem is column `9`, you need to make the spinner value a `java.sql.Time`

Comment: Here is my spinner declaration: `JSpinner timeSpinner = new JSpinner( new SpinnerDateModel() );
 JSpinner.DateEditor timeEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(timeSpinner, "HH:mm a");`

Comment: And then I added this: `javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel swingTime= timeEditor.getModel();
              java.sql.Time sqlTime= new java.sql.Time(swingTime.getCalendarField());`

Comment: `preparedStmt.setTime(9,sqlTime);`

Comment: And now the error which I am getting is: *Got an exception!
Incorrect integer value: 'Single' for column 'room_type' at row 1* .. room_type is a radio button and its data type is `tinyint(1)`

Comment: The [recommended mapping for tinyint](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.doc.html) seems to be `byte` or `short`

Comment: I changed the data type of `room_type` and `view_type` to `varchar` in the database as they were declared as String in the java codes.. It works fine now! Except for the time which is being written as 04:00:00 in the database for any time I input in the form. Can you please check the codes I wrote for the time in the comments above?

Comment: the data type I used for the time in the database table is `time`

Comment: You need to take the spinners value and convert it to a long which represetns the number of milliseconds since midnight, this value you then pass to `java.sql.Time` before binding it to your `PreparedStatement`

Comment: I don't get it.. This is my first GUI so sorry for the trouble

Comment: So `2:14am` is pretty meaningless to the database, instead, you need to convert this to milliseconds since midnight (which is what the `Time` class works in), so you'd need to break the `String` down into hours and minutes and convert these to milliseconds...of course, you could just a `SimpleDateFormat` which would give you a `Date` object, from which you could use `getTime` which would return you the value you need

Comment: But how would I "break the String down into hours and minutes and convert these to milliseconds"?

Comment: Let's just say, that's just basic programming, and if you have trouble grasping that, then you have bigger problems to deal with and should probably put GUI programming on hold. It's a bit hard to determine based on your code snippet, but if your `JSpinner` is configured to use `Date`, you could use `new java.sql.Timer(((java.util.Date)timeSpinner.getValue()).getTime());` which again is an example of you not understanding the basic API

Comment: Yes, it is configured to use `Date` I suppose. Here it is `JSpinner timeSpinner = new JSpinner( new SpinnerDateModel() );
 JSpinner.DateEditor timeEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(timeSpinner, "HH:mm a");`

Comment: it's `java.sql.Time` I suppose not `java.sql.Timer` as I am getting an error with `.Timer`

Comment: Sorry, did I write `Timer` :P force of habit, it's suppose to be `Time`

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the date from your dateChooser to a java.util.Date  using simpleDateFormat.
And after that you have to use setDate to write it o the db.
Parse the date:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd','yyyy");
preparedStmt.setDate(7,df.parse(((JTextField)dateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText()));
```

Comment: @kaanyılmaz You wrote the Code for formating as string. What is wrong in this case.

Comment: I got an exception message: *Got an exception!
Unparseable date: "Mar 10, 2016"*

Comment: @Jens it is not hard to write some sql insertion codes. I was trying to say " you can do it on your own" because it is not hard to do even if you know a little bit.

Comment: @Diksha sorry i had a blank to much

Comment: @kaanyılmaz But your Suggestion is wrong. OP should not change the date Format. he has to set the value as date

Comment: @Jens I said "if you get dates from your FRAME" so they would be string right ? ı'm just making suggesstions incase he/she needs it.

Comment: @kaanyılmaz yes it is a string. But it has to converted to a date, because the column type is date

Comment: @Jens java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();

java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String currentTime = sdf.format(dt); this is a date format which I provide as a code snipper and down that I made a suggestion if he/she needs string to date conversion.

Comment: String to date is sdf.parse(...)!

Answer (score 0):

Diksha, you are using wrong format for your database.

Mar 10, 2016 this is not acceptable for MySQL. Please use YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format.

Resource: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

```
java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();

java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);
```

currentTime will give you the default date format of MySQL (current date)

if you wish the change your own dates(like getting dates from your frame) to MySQL date format you could you use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879382/convert-string-to-mysql-date-format

Comment: Thanks! By the way, I am not sure if the data type in my database for multiple selection of checkboxes is correct. I wrote `room_facility tinyint(1) not null`

Comment: @Diksha if it helps you in right way, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Diksha I don't think it will make a big difference. Just try out and let us know.